# clBuildProgram returns CL_BUILD_PROGRAM_FAILURE, but no error occured

Tags: opencl

My program runs well on my machine. A user is getting strange error and currently I have no idea how to debug.

`clBuildProgram` returns -11 which indicates `CL_BUILD_PROGRAM_FAILURE`.

Call `clGetProgramBuildInfo` with `CL_PROGRAM_BUILD_STATUS`, it returns `CL_SUCCESS` and the build status is `CL_BUILD_SUCCESS`.

Call `clGetProgramBuildInfo` with `CL_PROGRAM_BUILD_LOG`, it returns `CL_SUCCESS` and the log is pasted below:

```
Compilation started
1:817:22: warning: array index -1 is before the beginning of the array
1:315:5: note: array 'event' declared here
1:884:20: warning: array index -1 is before the beginning of the array
1:315:5: note: array 'event' declared here
1:1095:40: warning: use of logical '||' with constant operand
1:1095:40: note: use '|' for a bitwise operation
1:1095:69: warning: use of logical '||' with constant operand
1:1095:69: note: use '|' for a bitwise operation
1:1109:42: warning: use of logical '||' with constant operand
1:1109:42: note: use '|' for a bitwise operation
1:1109:69: warning: use of logical '||' with constant operand
1:1109:69: note: use '|' for a bitwise operation
1:1372:71: warning: use of logical '||' with constant operand
1:1372:71: note: use '|' for a bitwise operation
Compilation done
Linking started
Linking done
Device build started
Device build done
Kernel <sim_iterate> was not vectorized
Done.
```

As the build log says, compilation & linking are done without any error. So what could be the problem?

The device is `Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-3240 CPU @ 3.40GHz`.

Comment: _My program runs well on my machine._ How does it with errors (kindly reported to you as warnings) like this: `array index -1 is before the beginning of the array` ?

Comment: @doqtor There is a heap pointer `_event_t* p = &event[-1];` so I can replace `event[i-1]` with `p[i]`. Compilers are complaining about this but I don't think this is an error.  The deﬁnition of the subscript operator `[]` is that `E1[E2]` is identical to `(*((E1)+(E2)))` (C99 6.5.2.1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the issue. The parameters of `clBuildProgram` is not correct.

```
// Before:
clBuildProgram(program, 0, 0, "-cl-single-precision-constant -cl-denorms-are-zero -cl-fast-relaxed-math", 0, 0)
// After:
clBuildProgram(program, 1, &device, "-cl-single-precision-constant -cl-denorms-are-zero -cl-fast-relaxed-math", 0, 0)
```